# How I de-duplicate records but at a user id level?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have entries related to the same person, but some columns are NULL in one row but not in another

```
Name | likes cats | likes dogs | likes fish | age
Bob  | true       | NULL       | FALSE      | NULL
Bob  | NULL       | true       | NULL       | NULL
Bob  | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | 50
Bob  | NULL       | NULL       | true       | NULL
```

All of these records are about Bob, but I'd have to aggregate them to get a complete picture. Is there a way to compact all these down and clear out the NULLs.

Compacted result would look like this.

```
Name | likes cats | likes dogs | likes fish | age
Bob  | true       | true       | FALSE      | 50
```

Comment: At the likes_fish column: Why is "false" taken and not "true"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bool_and()` as an aggregate for boolean:

```
select name, 
       bool_and(likes_cats) as likes_cats,
       bool_and(likes_dogs) as likes_dogs,
       bool_and(likes_fish) as likes_fish,
       max(age) as age
from data
group by name;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/XSOHVY82920

Answer (score 1):

This is sample code but you can use like:

```
select
      distinct on (name) name,
      likes_cats, 
      likes_dogs, 
      likes_fish, 
      age
from table
order by name, likes_cats NULLS LAST, likes_dogs NULLS LAST, likes_fish NULLS LAST, age  NULLS LAST
```